# Wavy Arcs in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, decorations, arc

I have the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) to (0,4) node[above]{\text{D1}};
    \draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) to (4,0) node[right]{\text{D3}};
    \filldraw (0,0) circle (3pt);
    \draw[snake=coil,segment aspect=0, line width=1.5pt, red] (0,1)  -- (1,0); 
    \draw[snake=coil,segment aspect=0, line width=1.5pt, green] (1.5,0) arc (180:0:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to make the arc to be snaky as the other red line. However, the code does not work. How can I make the green arc snaky?

Comment: Dear @percusse, thank you very much, it works!

Comment: @percusse Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @percusse, just another question: is it possible to adjust the segment aspect=0 for the arcs?

Comment: @QGravity Yes, you can find examples in the manual.

Comment: @percusse, Can you please mention which manual you are referring to?

Comment: [TikZ/pgf manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snake=coil` is a lucky miss such that `snake` is defined as the name of decoration and because of that supplying a value doesn't cause anything to happen. Hence if you fix the decoration name then it works. Hence instead of `snake=coil` use `decoration=snake,decorate`